# What does this excerpt of c++ mean?

Tags: c++

I'm simply trying to understand what is being reffered to by `dX()` or `dY()` in

```
Table2D<double> grad2(const Table2D<double>& intensity) {
    return grad2(intensity, dX(), dY());
}

Table2D<double> grad2(
    const Table2D<double>& intensity,
    const Kernel2D<double>& dX,
    const Kernel2D<double>& dY)
{
    Assert(
      dX.getWidth() <= intensity.getWidth()
   && dX.getHeight() <= intensity.getHeight(),
      "kernel 'dX' is bigger than array 'intensity' (in grad2)");
    Assert(!dX.isEmpty(), "kernel 'dX' is empty (in grad2)");  

    Table2D<double> Ix(intensity*dX), Iy(intensity*dY);
    return ((Ix%=Ix)+=(Iy%=Iy));
}
```

I have searched the document up and down with all sorts of settings in the finder window (case sensetive etc...) and I couldn't find a function with the name `dX()` or `dY()` anywhere. no namespace is being used either so it would have to reference something in the same document right?

Comment: Searched what document? Where is the code from?

Comment: We really can't give any meaningful answer without some more context.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me l.172 in `Math2D.h`.

Comment: code from my professor. The code works with no errors, I'm just trying to understand it

Comment: Which OS are you using and are you using an third party libraries?

Comment: @honk it IS in `Math2D.h` !! How did you know? doesn't matter.. what do you mean by 1.172 ?

Comment: @vvMINOvv: first hit on google for `Kernel2D<double>`. On line 172.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dX and dY (most probably denoting the partial derivatives in X and Y direction) could also have been declared in any file that is included via #include. Your best bet is to run the preprocessor on your file and look at the output. For gcc, when you call your compiler like

```
gcc -o foo.o [... stuff ...] -c bar.c
```

you can call the preprocessor as

```
cpp [... stuff ...] bar.c
```

Look at the output of the preprocessor and find the declaration of dX/dY.

Comment: I have to open my vm to check it out on linux, I'll let you know what happens. Thanks

Oh and yes it is the partial derivatives. The whole purpose of my question was for me to reverse engineer how he got his derivatives. I'm just curious.

If I can't figure it out, I think I'll just make a new question asking how to practically calculate the gradient of an image.

Comment: It seems I won't have access to gcc for a long time.Thanks for your help